# Fail2ban 0.9.0 enabling jails

Tags: fail2ban

I updated my server to 16.04 and it only installs fail2ban 0.9.0. There is no option to enable jails and when I add it manually it fails to load. Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Yeah, Fail2ban configuration files has changed a lot since V.0.9.X.

After V.0.9.X you should **NOT** change the original config file, that is located in

`/etc/fail2ban/jail.conf`

this is from Fail2ban jail.conf

```
# WARNING: heavily refactored in 0.9.0 release.  Please review and
#          customize settings for your setup.
#
# Changes:  in most of the cases you should not modify this
#           file, but provide customizations in jail.local file,
#           or separate .conf files under jail.d/ directory, e.g.:
#
# HOW TO ACTIVATE JAILS:
#
# YOU SHOULD NOT MODIFY THIS FILE.
#
# It will probably be overwritten or improved in a distribution update.
#
# Provide customizations in a jail.local file or a jail.d/customisation.local.
# For example to change the default bantime for all jails and to enable the
# ssh-iptables jail the following (uncommented) would appear in the .local file.
```

Ubuntu 16.04 installs Fail2ban V.0.9.3-1
To config it, do the following:

```
apt update
apt install fail2ban
```

after Fail2ban has been successfully installed:

```
cd /etc/fail2ban/
```

we now create some local jail, to override the default configurations

```
sudo nano /etc/fail2ban/jail.local
```

no copy and paste the following

```
[DEFAULT]
# Ban hosts for two days:
bantime = 172800

# Override /etc/fail2ban/jail.d/00-firewalld.conf:
banaction = iptables-multiport

[sshd]
enabled = true
```

now write to the file (ctrl + o) and close it (ctrl + x)

restart fail2ban service

```
sudo systemctl restart fail2ban
```

check fail2ban status

```
sudo fail2ban-client status
```

you should get a output like this:

```
Status
|- Number of jail:  1
`- Jail list:   sshd
```

now you check individuals jails e.g.

```
sudo fail2ban-client status sshd
```

with the above commands you can see which IP addresses has been blocked Fail2ban service!

you can control with systemctl is fail2ban is running or not

```
sudo systemctl status fail2ban
```

this is it.

PS: you can add other parameters like mail sending, find time, max-retry and ... if you would like!

Sources:

[How To Protect SSH With Fail2Ban on CentOS 7](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-protect-ssh-with-fail2ban-on-centos-7)

[Fail2ban with FirewallD](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Fail2ban_with_FirewallD)

[Using Fail2ban to Secure Your Server](https://www.linode.com/docs/security/using-fail2ban-for-security)

PS2: There is a newer version of Fail2ban available -> v0.9.4

If you would like, you can compile it yourself (read the [Fail2ban github page](https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban)) - though compiling IS NOT recommended 
From Fail2ban Github Page

> It is possible that Fail2ban is already packaged for your
>   distribution. In this case, you should use it instead.

OR

you can use the .dep package for the next version of Ubuntu (which is Yekkety)
[Package: fail2ban (0.9.4-1) [universe]](http://packages.ubuntu.com/yakkety/fail2ban)

Comment: ban host for two days :) awesome!

Comment: But how do i add the jail for apache. Every time i add enabled = true. Fail2ban fails to start. I use basic authentication with apache so this is a necessity. Currently i just reverted to 0.8 and put the update for fail2ban on hold with apt. I don't understand why they removed the ability to copy the .conf to a jail.local and manipulate the settings there. All the settings were already in the file. Maybe i am missing something. I have researched and couldn't find it on my own

Comment: @ILOVEKODI sorry man for answering late. Just Copy the apache section or whatever the webserver section is, to the jail.local and add enabled = true / like we did it with the SSH. Hope this help. :) [http://notes.sagredo.eu/node/170] you may check out this website.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to [bossModus's info](https://askubuntu.com/a/798825/527764), note that there is no `apache` jail in the newer versions of `fail2ban`.  I believe it was renamed to `apache-auth`.